# Where is there a break in my SVG section divider?

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to create an SVG divider between two sections of my website (each section has min-height:100vh). However, I noticed that when I try to view the site in mobile-mode, there is a small break between where the SVG section divider ends and where the section begins. How do I get rid of it? I've attached two pictures of what it looks like when I view it on mobile.
[Line break image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8Ich.png) (image shows a slight line break on the purple and pink half of the svg-- pink is kind of faint and blends into white so may be hard to see) and
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjVB4.png.

Here is my codesandbox (let me know if you can't access it): https://codesandbox.io/embed/wizardly-bas-2wxp3g?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Once you open up the project, you have to enter development mode and view it as a mobile phone in order to see the line break. (it's pretty faint)

Here is my HTML code and a link to the svg (https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Layer_wave.svg):

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <body>
      <section id="sec1">
        section1
      </section>
      <div class="spacer layer_wave"></div>
      <section id="sec2"></section>
    </body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is my CSS for the SVG and section:

```css
#sec1 {
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgb(128, 141, 214);
  display: flex;

  /*Font*/
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

#sec2 {
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  background: #e3d8de;
  display: flex;

  /*Font*/
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

.layer_wave {
  background-image: url("layer_wave.svg");
}
.spacer {
  aspect-ratio: 960/300;
  width: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a minimum working example, not screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

Normally this is because of the scaling elements on the screen when they try to translate between pixels. The easiest way to fix this would be to just add a `margin-top:-1px;` To the container of the SVG element, then it will never leave a potential gap between itself and the previous section.

So change `.spacer` to:

```css
.spacer {
  aspect-ratio: 960/300;
  width: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  margin-top:-1px;
}
```

Have a great day!